# passing polynomial coefficients generated from one function to another

Tags: python

Since I have been writing a big python program for my project. I have another query of which I cant figure out the solution. Here is the code.

```
poly = [[k6,3], [k5,2], [k4,1], [k0,0]]

w = 5  # weight for rational bezier curve equation

def time() :
    with open(transcriptionFile, "r") as tFile :
            for line in tFile :
                li = line.split()
                if li :
                    start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                    end_time = (int(li[1]) / 10000000.) 
                    duration = ((int(li[1]) -int(li[0]))/10000000.)
                    print start_time,' ',end_time,' ',duration
                    poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, duration)

def poly_coeff(stime, etime, dur) :
    """The equation is k6 * u^3 + k5 * u^2 + k4 * u + k0 = 0. Computing the        coefficients of this equation."""
    """Substituting the required values we get the coefficients."""
    t_u = dur
    t0 = stime
    t3 = etime
    t1 = t2 = (stime + etime) / 2
    w0 = w1 = w2 = w3 = w
    k0 = w0 * (t_u - t0)
    k1 = w1 * (t_u - t1)
    k2 = w2 * (t_u - t2)
    k3 = w3 * (t_u - t3)
    k4 = 3 * (k1 - k0)
    k5 = 3 * (k2 - 2 * k1 + k0)
    k6 = k3 - 3 * k2 + 3 * k1 -k0 
    print k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    if len(sys.argv) != 2 : 
        Usage() 

    else :
        transcriptionFile = sys.argv[1]

        time()

    Newton(poly, 0.42, 1, 0)
```

There is a list of start time, end time and their duration. All of them are passed to the function poly_coeff() to generate the polynomial coefficients. There will be as many as there are in the list. Then for each polynomial generated, its corresponding coefficients should be passed as poly to Newton() function to carry out other calculations. And at the top, the polynomial is represented as poly. In poly, each k6, k5, k4 and k0 values generated should be passed. Of course it is not how to do but just to clear what I am trying to do. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow of your code was quite confusing. I assume that you want to calculate the poly for each line of your input file, then call `Newton(poly, 0.42, 1, 0)`.

I changed your `time()` function to take the filename as a parameter, and changed your poly_coeff method to return the poly you have calculated. Then in the `for line in tFile:` loop in `time()`, I get the result from `poly_coeff()` and pass that into `Newton()`.

Hopefully that is close to what you want to do...

```
def time(fileName) :
    with open(fileName, "r") as tFile :
            for line in tFile :
                li = line.split()
                if li :
                    start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                    end_time = (int(li[1]) / 10000000.) 
                    duration = ((int(li[1]) -int(li[0]))/10000000.)
                    print start_time,' ',end_time,' ',duration

                    poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, duration)
                    Newton(poly, 0.42, 1, 0)

def poly_coeff(stime, etime, dur) :
    """The equation is k6 * u^3 + k5 * u^2 + k4 * u + k0 = 0. Computing the        coefficients of this equation."""
    """Substituting the required values we get the coefficients."""
    w = 5  # weight for rational bezier curve equation

    t_u = dur
    t0 = stime
    t3 = etime
    t1 = t2 = (stime + etime) / 2
    w0 = w1 = w2 = w3 = w
    k0 = w0 * (t_u - t0)
    k1 = w1 * (t_u - t1)
    k2 = w2 * (t_u - t2)
    k3 = w3 * (t_u - t3)
    k4 = 3 * (k1 - k0)
    k5 = 3 * (k2 - 2 * k1 + k0)
    k6 = k3 - 3 * k2 + 3 * k1 -k0 
    print k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6

    return [[k6,3], [k5,2], [k4,1], [k0,0]]


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 : 
        Usage()
    else :
        transcriptionFile = sys.argv[1]

        time(transcriptionFile)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. What is the difference between passing the file in time() function and not passing anything and open in the open statement.

Comment: The main difference is that it makes it more obvious where the value is coming from. It also makes the code more reusable.

Comment: Thank you. I have another query which I will post in a while after I discuss with my tutor.

Answer (score 1):

To return the calculated results of a function or method you have to use the `return` statement.

In `poly_coeff()`:

```
...
return k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6
```

should do just fine. The results can be saved into variables in your `time()` function like this:

```
...
k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6 = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, duration)
# do something with the values here ....
```

**UPDATE:** the first line in the script does not work, because k6, .. do not exist at that time. One option is to return the `poly` in your `poly_coeff` function. For example like that:

```
def poly_coeff(...):
    ...
    return [[k6,3], [k5,2], [k4,1], [k0,0]]
```

now, in `time` you can retrieve the `poly` like that:

```
def time():
    ...
    poly = poly_coeff(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using the return statement. But it displays an error pointing to poly at the beginning and says k6 is not defined. May be declaring them as global will solve it not sure. I only need to pass k6, k5, k4 and k0 as only they will be used for calculations further.

Comment: Well, `k6` is defined. If you do only need k6, k5, k4 and k0 you can only return those: `return k6, k5, k4, k0`

Comment: Yes I did the same but it says. poly = [[k6,3], [k5,2], [k4,1], [k0,0]]

Comment: sorry and then it displays as NameError: name k6 is not defined

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I understand. You try to initialize your variable `poly`, but the elements k6 etc do not yet exist. I'll update my answer, to propose a solution.

Comment: But time() doesnt need poly. time() calls poly_coeff() which generates k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5 and k6. Then k6, k5, k4 and k0 should be passed in poly which is used by Newton() function. Thanks